# User.Identity.GetUserName() Will Not Display Anything

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to simply display the username the same way it does on the _LoginPartial.cshtml in a particular field on my Create.cshtml page.

I have this at the top:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
```

And in the cshtml I have:

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreatedBy, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="form-control-static">
                @Html.Display(User.Identity.GetUserName())
                @Html.Hidden(User.Identity.GetUserName())
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CreatedBy, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

But when the page is displayed, despite the username appearing at the top in the built in partial, it won't show up where it should in the form. Nothing appears there. No errors.

Comment: Please take note of your tags - and when it say DO NOT USE, then please do not use.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So turns out that the only way I could manage to pass the current user's e-mail to the create page was to create a new instance of the model and set the "CreatedBy" property in the GET method of the controller, then pass that model to the view and use DisplayFor.

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        NewUser nu = new NewUser();
        nu.CreatedBy = User.Identity.Name;
        ViewBag.DepartmentId = new SelectList(db.departments, "DepartmentId", "DepartmentName");
        ViewBag.LocationId = new SelectList(db.locations, "LocationId", "LocationName");
        return View(nu);
    }
```

And

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreatedBy, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="form-control-static">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.CreatedBy, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CreatedBy)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CreatedBy, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

**Check Possible Authentication Issues**

The [`GetUserName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.identityextensions.getusername(v=vs.108).aspx) method will only return the name of the currently authenticated user, so if you aren't logged into any of the existing accounts, it will be empty.

This can vary depending on the authentication mode of your application (i.e. Forms-based authentication, Windows, etc.), which can generally be seen within the `<authentication>` section of your web.config file :

```
<!-- Forms-based authentication (i.e. default username/password scenario) -->
<authentication mode="Forms"/> 
<!-- Windows-based authentication (i.e. use current account) -->
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
```

Within a File > New Project scenario, forms authentication is likely going to be enabled (unless it was explicitly unchecked), so you should simply be able to create a new account and then log into the account to see the user name properly displayed within the View.

**Consider Alternative Usage**

If you are sure that your authentication isn't the underlying issue, consider avoiding the HTML Helper methods entirely and simply outputting the values to a hidden field using either the existing `GetUserName()` method or the `User.Identity.Name` property, which should return the same value assuming you haven't tinkered with the Claims:

```
<div class="form-control-static">
   <!-- Either of these approaches should work if you are authenticated -->
   <input type='hidden' value='@User.Identity.GetUserName()' />
   <input type='hidden' value='@User.Identity.Name' />
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CreatedBy, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

**If all else fails...**

If neither of the proposed solutions seem to be working, then it's likely that something may have not be configured correctly within your project (namely the built-in Identity logic).

This could likely be the case if you created an empty project and then simply pasted some code from the default template, in which the Identity wouldn't be set up properly.

Comment: I am logged in hence the fact that it's correctly displaying the username in the loginPartial. If I weren't logged in it wouldn't be showing that. I tried User.Identity.Name as well, no such luck.

Comment: IIRC, the LoginPartial view generally uses `User.Identity.Name` so that should be working in some way, shape, or form so that _should_ be working. You might want to consider checking your exact LoginPartial view to confirm that. Additionally, have you tried placing a breakpoint within the vew (or related controller action) to see what value `User.Identity` has and its properties.

Comment: It actually uses the GetUserName() method, that's how I became aware of the method to begin with. Changing the HTML doesn't do anything. I'm not sure why it can't get the current user logged in. It's a forms login using Google OAuth.

Answer (score 0):

Try `@Html.DisplayFor()` instead:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x=>User.Identity.Name)
```

or maybe

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x=>User.Identity.GetUserName())
```

Comment: That's not how that works I don't think. I tried it just to see but that won't work.

Comment: Fair enough.  I don't believe the behavior was consistent from one version of ASP.NET MVC to the next, and this does work on an MVC 4 application that I have been recently editing.